# Issue with reading message from MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

We have two systems, A and B. The communication channel between these two is MQ. Recently B version has been upgraded to newer version and communication has failed.

The process is like in previous version: B will place response in queue and A will read from Response queue and process it. In the newer version, B is placing the message in queue, but A could not able to read it. Depth of the Response queue is increasing each time when response is placed in queue.

We verified the contents of the Message and it seems the same as in the older version. When we connect to B's older version, it works fine and A is able to read the message, but if we change to the newer version **reading is not happening**.

There are no errors in errors/AMQERR01.LOG or in the application logs. Don't know why reading the message is not happening with new B response.

I just want to know about these **MQ values** will affect on this **NOT READING issue**: JMS_IBM_Character_Set, JMSMessageID, JMS_IBM_MsgType, JMSXUserID, JMS_IBM_Encoding, JMS_IBM_Report_Pass_Correl_ID, JMSXAppID, JMS_IBM_PutApplType, JMS_IBM_Format, JMS_IBM_PutDate, JMSXDeliveryCount, JMS_IBM_PutTime, JMSCorrelationID.

> feb 1 2018

MQMessage mqMsg, MQGetMessageOptions mqGMO
above parameters are used to read the message from queue.
When we connect to B's older version now, it works fine and A is able to read the message, but if we change to the newer version reading is not happening.
No upgrade happened in MQ side. "MQGetMessageOptions" will have any impact on not reading?

> feb 6 2018
>   expected MQOptions

- processQMessage
- mqMsg.format:MQSTR
- mqMsg.characterSet:819
- mqMsg.encoding:273
- mqGMO.options:24581
- msgAppId:txn_Risk
- msgSenderRef:a6ac1633b6ca898e

```
protected byte[] readMQMessage(MQMessage argMQMsg, String argClient,
String argApp)
        throws IOException  
    {  
        String methodName = "readMQMessage";  
        Log.debug(argClient, 
                argApp,
                this,
                LogCategory.PRODUCTION,
                methodName + "getMessageLength");  

        int dataLength = argMQMsg.getMessageLength();  
        byte [] hostDataBuffer = new byte[dataLength];  

        argMQMsg.readFully(hostDataBuffer);  
        return hostDataBuffer;  
    }
```

problem here with new version, on debug mode, its not entering to this loop
but with older version, on debug mode, its entering and performing tasks as expected.

I suspect in two things

1. MQOptions / MQ values missing in newer version
2. Will MQMessage character impacting in reading?

> feb 22 2018

- when i debug , eclipse pointer will come till 'processQMessage' function and not going inside function , which should read message in QM

> ```
> /**  
>  * Called by the port after a message is taken from the Q.  
>  * @param mqMsg An IBM MQ message object pulled from the Queue, ready to be
>  * processed.  
>  * @param mqGMO The IBM MQGetMessageOptions object used during the GET  
>  * operation that retrieved the message to be processed.  
>  */  
> public void processQMessage( MQMessage mqMsg, MQGetMessageOptions mqGMO )  
> {  
> ---   
> ---  
> readMQMessage()
> ---  
> }
> ```

I suspect in two things
 1. MQOptions / MQ values missing in newer version
 2. Will MQMessage character impacting in reading?

**I want know about MQMD and CCSID. Is this issue comes with MQMD and CCSID?**

> feb 26 2018

Full code which read Message from MQ , not clear to view headers in linux

```
    /**
* Called by the port after a message is taken from the Q.
* @param mqMsg An IBM MQ message object pulled from the Queue, ready to be
* processed.
* @param mqGMO The IBM MQGetMessageOptions object used during the GET
* operation that retrieved the message to be processed.
*/
public void processQMessage( MQMessage mqMsg, MQGetMessageOptions mqGMO )
{
final String methodName = "processQMessage: ";
long  safeStoreStatus       = 0;
String msgSenderRef         = null;
String msgAppId              = null;
XMLTag checkXML         = new XMLTag();
DispatchMessage m           = null;
String msgClientID          = null; //ClientID for this message

Log.debug(m_clientID,m_applicationID,this,LogCategory.PRODUCTION,methodName + "processQMessage");
Log.debug(m_clientID, m_applicationID,this,LogCategory.PRODUCTION,methodName + "mqMsg.format:" + mqMsg.format);
Log.debug(m_clientID, m_applicationID,this,LogCategory.PRODUCTION,methodName + "mqMsg.characterSet:" + mqMsg.characterSet);
Log.debug(m_clientID, m_applicationID,this,LogCategory.PRODUCTION,methodName + "mqMsg.encoding:" + mqMsg.encoding);
Log.debug(m_clientID, m_applicationID,this,LogCategory.PRODUCTION,methodName + "mqGMO.options:" + mqGMO.options);


}
```

> 26 FEB 2018 (2)

before executing amqsbcg command, i verified depth of as below

```
display qstatus(TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS)
     1 : display qstatus(TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS)
AMQ8450: Display queue status details.
   QUEUE(TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS)                 TYPE(QUEUE)
   CURDEPTH(1)                             IPPROCS(0)
   LGETDATE( )                             LGETTIME( )
   LPUTDATE( )                             LPUTTIME( )
   MEDIALOG( )                             MONQ(OFF)
   MSGAGE( )                               OPPROCS(0)
   QTIME( , )                              UNCOM(NO)
```

but below command dint show any headers..

```
./amqsbcg TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS NEWMQ850.QM

AMQSBCG0 - starts here
**********************

 MQOPEN - 'TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS'



 No more messages
 MQCLOSE
```

> 27 FEB 2018 (1)

When i perform, sample / expected response via ./amqsput and then executed ./amqsbcg , it shows all values and Message data. I don't know why when application written message , depth increased and not getting any values with ./amqsbcg. Please help

> 28 FEB 2018 (1)

<>Are you sure that no process connected and "GET" the message from the queue between the time you displayed and ran amqsbcg?
***i will stop application which read message from QM, that is the reason depth showing as  1 , else it should be 0.Something is different coming from new version system, NOT message contents, some external parameters causing the problem***
<>One possibility is the message was not yet committed
***how to find that?Team says nothing changed in New sys***
<>but the UNCOM(NO) indicates that no uncommitted messages are on the queue
***other differences i saw is MQ7client to MQ7Server(old sys) and MQ9Client to MQ7Server***

> 28 FEB 2018 (2)

```
   <1>Ensure that your application is not asking for a specific message ID or correlation ID when it should be processing all the messages on the queue.  
    <2>Although the current depth of the queue might show that there is an increasing number of messages on the queue, some messages on the queue might not be available to be got by an application, because they are not committed; the current depth includes the number of uncommitted MQPUTs of messages to the queue. Issue the following command:
    DISPLAY QSTATUS(Q1) TYPE(QUEUE) ALLcopy to clipboard
    In the output, look at the UNCOM field to see whether there are any uncommitted messages on the queue.  
   <3> If your application is attempting to get any messages from the queue, check whether the putting application is committing the messages correctly. Issue the following command to find out the names of applications that are putting messages to this queue:
    DISPLAY QSTATUS(Q1) TYPE(HANDLE) OPENTYPE(OUTPUT)  
    <4>Then issue the following command, inserting in appltag the APPLTAG value from the output of the previous command:
    DISPLAY CONN(*) WHERE(APPLTAG EQ appltag) UOWSTDA UOWSTTI  
    This shows when the unit of work was started and will help you discover whether the application is creating a long running unit of work. If the putting application is a channel, you might want to investigate why a batch is taking a long time to complete
```

> 01 MAR 2018 (1)

Another key testing results as below

1. Exercise is simple and results are mind blowing!!!! . When we send  Request to new system, I found like depth of Queue TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS has been increased in NEWMQ850.QM. New Exercise done like ,  cleared queue TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS and placed same message via MQ put command[amqsput] and restarted application. Result shows like our application able to read new Message , processed it and updated in UI with right status as new system response below.
2. Here is the golden stuff , when new system application write into TXN_RCV_FRM_SYS Queue , missed some stuffs like commit of transaction / misplaced of Message Headers /  wrong MessageID and CorelationID  / ……
3. This  exercise also shows, we can rule out the issue not related to Message contents

> 04 Mar 2018

Some one known , how to debug this issue?
What all possible reasons to see in code?
Please help

Comment: What is the logic used by A to read the response from the Response queue?  Was the IBM MQ product the component that was upgraded for B or was something else upgraded?

Comment: You will have to provide the actual code around reading the message.  You provided mqMsg would looks like it would old the message and you provided mqGMO which has the Get Message Options but you have not provided what the Get Message Options are set to or how the message is read from the queue.

Comment: If the problem is that `readMQMessage` is not being called them you need to show us the logic that would call `readMQMessage` not `readMQMessage` itself.

Comment: Can you provide headers as viewed by the `amqsbcg` sample app for both old and new messages.  Can you show the **ACTUAL** code that shows the MQ API calls used to GET the messages from the queue.

Comment: Are you sure that no process connected and "GET" the message from the queue between the time you displayed and ran amqsbcg?  One possibility is the message was not yet committed, but the UNCOM(NO) indicates that no uncommitted messages are on the queue.